# Using fixed point iteration find the positive root of $f(x)=e^{-x}-x^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Consider $f(x)=e^{-x}-x^2$.

I'm  suppose to find the positive root using fixed point iteration.

after drawing the graph, it's safe to set the interval from [0.25,1].
(I actually want to set it from [0.5,1] but i'm unsure as i can't zoom into the graph).

The problem i'm having is deriving the function $g$.

I got $g(x)=-2\ln(x)$.

I can't seem to prove the uniqueness of this root as $g'(x)=\frac{-2}{x}$ but i can bound $|g'(x)|<K$ such that K<1 under this interval. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried to think of other $g(x)$ but none of them seem convergent to me

Comment: Are you asking how to prove that f(x) has a unique positive root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $g(x)=e^{-x/2}$ works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/584937)

Comment: @Lovsovs I think you will find as you get more experience here, sometimes we don't give a full detailed solution that assumes the OP is an idiot.  This answer gives enough to move him away from the log formula to one that does work.

Comment: Yes, perhaps you are right, I might have jumped the gun a bit. Sorry for the inconvenience then!

Comment: @Michael yeah thanks for that. When manipulating the f(x) equation, I was focused on eliminating the exponential term so i never considered this option. thanks for the help! it really did help me move forward!

Answer (score 0):

*Hint-* Try $x=e^{-x/2}=g(x)$ such that $|g'(x)|<1$ for $x\in(0,1)$

Answer (score 0):

Since you've proved $|g'(x)| < K$ with $ K < 1 $ You can use the mean value theorem that states that for all $x,y$ in $[0.25,1]$ $|g(x)-g(y)|\le K|x-y]$

Let $l_1$ and $l_2$ be fixed points of g in $[0.25,1]$ 
$$ |g(l_1)-g(l_2)| \le K|l_1-l_2| $$ Since $g(l_1) = l_1$ and $g(l_2) = l_2$
$$ |l_1-l_2| \le K|l_1-l_2|$$ 
$$ (|l_1-l_2|)(1-K) \le 0 $$
And since $K \lt 1$ then $1-K \gt 0$ which leads us to $|l_1 - l_2| \le 0$ however we know $|l_1 - l_2| \ge 0$ We can conclude that $ l_1 = l_2 $ Which proves the uniqueness of the fixed point of $g$ and thus the uniqueness of the  of $f$

And as others suggested, i think $g \mapsto e^{-x/2}$ works better